# server side validation error

Tags: hibernate, validation

I am doing server side validation. I have 1 page with dropdown list if I select **user1**, it will display roll no( which is long type in bean class),name, class, email id. And if I select **user2** then it will hide roll no and other fields will be shown. But while clicking on submit button for **user2** it is validating the hidden field of rollno and showing the error as **Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type long for property retailerId; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:**.

Below is my bean class code

```
private long rollNo;
@SafeHtml
private String name,
@SafeHtml
private String class
@SafeHtml
private String email
---setter and getter of above--
```

in Jsp file

```
<form:input tabindex="32" class="form-control" path="rollNo" placeholder="Enter rollNo" title="rollNo"
                                data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="6" data-rule-maxlength="6"
                                data-msg-required="Enter a valid rollNo"
                                data-msg-minlength="Enter a valid rollNo"
                                data-msg-maxlength="Enter a valid rollNo"/>
```

```
$("#createUserForm").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {                   
                $("div.errorContainer").show().text("data missing");
            } else {
                $("div.errorContainer").hide();
            }
        },
        ignore : ':hidden',         
    });
```

Could you please let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: Simply check `roll no` for being null or empty when you receive a request and before you parse it.

Comment: It should not validate the roll no for user2 as rollno is hidden. Moreever if I put @NotNull also it is showing same error.

Comment: I solved it. Instead of **long rollNo** I made it **Long rollNo** which works